How to add an external folder to the setup bundle in electron-forge?
I'm using electron-forge + vite + typescript and I have a folder that I want to be added to the setup file including its files when I run npm run make, so when I install the app this folder appears in the app install location. I've searched but I couldn't find how to do this building with electron-forge + vite.
The project structure is the following:
project-folder
|
|-src
|
|-public (the folder I want to add)

I checked the documentation, looked for some hints in the electron-forge's github repo and searched in google about it, even asked chatgpt.
Thanks in advance.

By default electron copy all js and tsx files. other extensions need to be pointed in order to be copied.
if its a file you need to be copied you can add a files list in build section of package.json
"files": [
      "logs.txt",
    ]

if its a directory, you can add extraResources list in the same location :
"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./data",
        "to": "data",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      "./assets/**",
    ]

